# unable to figure out how a windbg extension work

Tags: windows, windbg

I'm trying to figure out how the below windbg extension works

```
!ndiskd.nbl  addr  -hexcap(or -data)
```

```
kd> !ndiskd.nbl ffffce8c96bde070 -hexcap
# NET_BUFFER_LIST    ffffce8c96bde070
# NET_BUFFER     ffffce8c96bde1f0
# MDL    ffffce8c96bde2c8
00000000       30 39 20 b1 97 42 11 bb 00 00 20 b2 60 12 ff 70
00000010       34 b7 00 00
```

This looks quite fine because it starts with the header. The address is ffffce8c96bde3f4. But I'm unable to find or compute the value with elements in the structures. So I take a deep look at associated structs.

```
NET_BUFFER_LIST
   +0x000 Next             : NULL
   +0x008 FirstNetBuffer   : Oxffffce8c'96bde1f0
   +0x000 Link             : _SLIST_HEADER
   +0x000 NetBufferListHeader : _NET_BUFFER_LIST_HEADER
   +0x010 Context          : Oxffffce8c'96bde2a0 _NET_BUFFER_LIST_CONTEXT
   +0x018 ParentNetBufferList : NULL
   +0x020 NdisPoolHandle   : ...
   +0x030 NdisReserved     : ...
   +0x040 ProtocolReserved : ...
   +0x060 MiniportReserved : ...
   +0x070 Scratch          : ...
   +0x078 SourceHandle     : ...
   +0x080 NblFlags         : ...
   +0x084 ChildRefCount    : ...
   +0x088 Flags            : ...
   +0x08c Status           : ...
   +0x08c NdisReserved2    : ...
   +0x090 NetBufferListInfo : ...
```

FirstNetBuffer. The MDL is where system store data

```
NET_BUFFER
   +0x000 Next             : NULL
   +0x008 CurrentMdl       : ffffce8c96bde2c8
   +0x010 CurrentMdlOffset : 0xec
   +0x018 DataLength       : 0x14
   +0x018 stDataLength     : 0x14   //The length, in bytes, of the used data space in the MDL chain
   +0x020 MdlChain         : ffffce8c96bde2c8
   +0x028 DataOffset       : 0xec
   +0x000 Link             : _SLIST_HEADER
   +0x000 NetBufferHeader  : _NET_BUFFER_HEADER
   +0x030 ChecksumBias     : ...
   +0x032 Reserved         : ...
   +0x038 NdisPoolHandle   : ...
   +0x040 NdisReserved     : ...
   +0x050 ProtocolReserved : ...
   +0x080 MiniportReserved : ...
   +0x0a0 DataPhysicalAddress : ...
   +0x0a8 SharedMemoryInfo : ...
   +0x0a8 ScatterGatherList : ...
```

CurrentMdl

```
MDL 
   +0x000 Next             : NULL
   +0x008 Size             : 0n56
   +0x00a MdlFlags         : 0n4
   +0x00c AllocationProcessorNumber : ...
   +0x00e Reserved         : ...
   +0x010 Process          : Ptr64 _EPROCESS
   +0x018 MappedSystemVa   : Oxffffce8c'96bde308
   +0x020 StartVa          : Oxffffce8c'96bde000
   +0x028 ByteCount        : 0x100
   +0x02c ByteOffset       : 0x308
```

OK. Now from MDL I know that system allocates 0x100 bytes for the data. And the first around 0x70 are 0s which is normal. Like I said the data starts with ffffce8c96bde3f4, if I use the Mdloffset(ec) and currentMdl(ffffce8c96bde2c8), I get ffffce8c96bde3b4. The difference is 0x40. But with all the values, I don't know where the 0x40 comes from. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer is printed from CurrentMdl->MappedSystemVa+CurrentMdlOffset upto Size-CurrentOffset

When there is an MDLChain the data is printed for all Next->MappedSystemVa

And when posting output from windbg do not edit and insert your own address in the first dump the address starts from 0 but it should start from 308+ec == 3f4

I could have answered this earlier if i saw 3f4 i was not sure how 00000000 came there so i had to verify before posting

The output from !nbl xxxx -data  actually outputs the correct address not some 0x00000000

a sample output

```
0: kd> .lastevent
Last event: Hit breakpoint 0
  
0: kd> r
ndis!NdisSendNetBufferLists:
fffff802`373b2460 44894c2420      mov     dword ptr [rsp+20h],r9d ss:0018:fffff802`38077048=00000000

0: kd> !nbl @rdx -data
NET_BUFFER ffffcb8dc6f83600
  MDL ffffcb8dc65f1180
    ffffcb8dc65f11e2  33 33 00 00 00 16 00 0c-29 45 de 6c 86 dd 60 00  33······)E·l··`·
    ffffcb8dc65f11f2  00 00 00 24 00 01 fe 80-00 00 00 00 00 00 db 08  ···$············
    ffffcb8dc65f1202  d6 ac 7c b4 bc 33 ff 02-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ··|··3··········
    ffffcb8dc65f1212  00 00 00 00 00 16                                ······
  MDL ffffcb8dc72e9a40
    ffffcb8dc65f10ae  3a 00 05 02 00 00 01 00-8f 00 c9 83 00 00 00 01  :···············
    ffffcb8dc65f10be  04 00 00 00 ff 02 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  ················
    ffffcb8dc65f10ce  ff b4 bc 33                                      ···3
```

set up a Pseudo Register for ease of use

```
0: kd> r? $t1 = ((ndis!_NET_BUFFER_LIST *)@rdx)->FirstNetBuffer
```

address of First Buffer

```
0: kd> ? @@c++(@$t1->CurrentMdl->MappedSystemVa) + @@c++(@$t1->CurrentMdlOffset)
Evaluate expression: -57665197764126 = ffffcb8d`c65f11e2
```

address of Second Buffer

```
0: kd> ? @@c++(@$t1->MdlChain->Next->MappedSystemVa)
Evaluate expression: -57665197764434 = ffffcb8d`c65f10ae
```